# Explain the use of "str - '0'" when converting a string to an integer.

Tags: string, matlab

I have noticed that a really cool method to convert a string, say

```
str = '1234'
```

to a vector is to use this trick.

```
vec = str - '0'
 = [1 2 3 4]
```

My question is why does this method work?

Further, something like:

```
vec1 = str -'1'
  = [0 1 2 3]
```

but

```
vec2 = str - '10'
  Error using  - 
  Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

What is taking place here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use arithmetic operators with strings, Matlab casts the strings as doubles, which converts a string to ascii values:

```
>> double('1')
ans =
    49
```

Thus, subtraction will work just fine, though addition will give weird results

```
>> '1'+'1'
ans =
    98
```

Converting an array of strings to double results in an *array* of doubles, therefore the "matrix dimensions must agree":

```
>> double('10')
ans =
    49    48
```

Thus, while subtracting `'0'` is thus a cool shortcut, I suggest you use [STR2DOUBLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/str2double.html) instead to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks, @Jonas.  Clear explanation!